# if this echo this - if variable not there echo nothing

Tags: php

I have added a script to my website which shows a message when the product filter does not show up any results. The code I've included is this:

```
<?php
if(empty($htmlFilter->rows)){
  echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>';
}
?>
```

This works, but the problem I'm having is that the message also shows up on the pages where the filter is not existent. I need to write a condition for when the filter does not exists on the page.

Can anyone help please?

Quick update: When I add var_dump($htmlFilter) it come sup with NULL

Is the variable not right?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would expect an undefined variable error, but it silently just evaluates to `true` even though the variable is not set, which is a bad thing because not everyone is aware of this.

As a workaround you can additionally check if the variable is set before checking if its value is empty.

```
if (isset($htmlFilter) && empty($htmlFilter->rows)) {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the isset function like this if I got what you wrote right.

```
<?php
if(empty($htmlFilter->rows) && isset($htmlFilter)){
  echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>';
}
?>
```

EDIT:

This code:

```
<?php
echo is_null($algo);
echo '<br>';
echo isset($algo);
echo '<br>';
echo empty($algo);
?>
```

returns this:

```
1

1
```

As you can see, the variable $algo is not initialized nor declared.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys....I've tried all three options, but none of them work :-( The scripts given remove the message alltogether when selecting a search that does not bring anything up. See here: https://www.elevateyoursole.co.uk/womensshoes

Comment: @Carania try adding a line with this in your script

 var_dump($htmlFilter);


and paste the result in your question.

Comment: Hi Tomas, I've just done it and it came up with a message where the echo message was.... it says NULL :-(  What does that mean?

Comment: @Carania, probably because it's not set. Where does that var is initialized?

Just to try to brute force a solution, you could try with the 'is_null()' function

Comment: I have no idea what the correct var name is...it's a hikashop installation and I was told by the support that it is $htmlFilter. Can i find out somehow how to set or find the correct $ ?

Comment: @Carania, if you aren't trying this in production you could add this line to the script.  

    `var_dump(get_defined_vars());`  


You can check the vars with that. DON'T DO THIS IN PRODUCTION.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try...

```
<?php
if( isset($htmlFilter->rows) && empty($htmlFilter->rows) ) {
  echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If $htmlFilter->rows is supposed to be an array, you can do this:

```
<?php
if(isset($htmlFilter->rows) && count($htmlFilter->rows) === 0){
  echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fixed this - I used the following code:

```
if(empty($this->rows) && !empty($htmlFilter)){
echo '<p>Sorry, no results found - try a different search selection</p>'
```

It was also not put in the correct line :-/

All sorted now though - thanks for your help guys! :-)